# Trouble with Data Binding properties within custom Pin class using Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, class, xamarin, data-binding

I'm having trouble setting the data binding for some custom properties within a custom Pin class using Xamarin forms.

Here is the two custom classes I'm dealing with.

```
public class CustomPin : Pin
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty NameProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Name", typeof(string), typeof(Pin), default(string));

    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }

    public string Icon { get; set; }
}

public class UserData
{
    public string Callsign { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Team { get; set; }
    public CustomPin Pin { get; set; }
    public Position Position { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the element that holds the values of my Bindings.

```
public static UserData myUserData = new UserData
{
    Callsign = "User",
    Pin = new CustomPin
    {
        BindingContext = myUserData,
        Position = new Position(),
        Name = "",
        Label = ""
    },
    Position = new Position(),
};
```

Here is how I set the bindings

```
myUserData.Pin.SetBinding(CustomPin.PositionProperty, "Position");
myUserData.Pin.SetBinding(CustomPin.LabelProperty, "Callsign");
myUserData.Pin.SetBinding(CustomPin.NameProperty, "Callsign");
```

And there is the method I use to debug

```
Debug.WriteLine
(
    myUserData.Pin.Name + " should be " + myUserData.Callsign + "\n" +
    myUserData.Pin.Label + " should be " + myUserData.Callsign + "\n" +
    myUserData.Pin.Position.Latitude + " should be " + myUserData.Position.Latitude + "\n" +
    myUserData.Pin.Position.Longitude + " should be " + myUserData.Position.Longitude + "\n"
);
```

Here is the output, as you can see it doesn't apply the bindings - however I do use this bindings in other objects (such as Xamarin.Forms.Label) and they work just fine.

```
 should be User
 should be User
0 should be 37.63150086
0 should be -122.43626643
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: what you're doing makes no sense at all.  First, `Pin` is a UI object, yet you're embedding it in a data class.  Then you're trying to use binding to tie a value from the data class to the custom `Pin` class that is a child of the data class.

Comment: @Jason I have to handle multiple users from the server and the simplest way of doing that is to store the userData and Pins together in the same class. If the users location is updated then I'd like the pin to automatically update its location without having to specifically tell it - clearly that is the workaround but this is more a learning point for me than trying to force code everything through.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Jason said that `Pin is a UI object`. You should not make it as a data class. You can use it in the .xaml file or you can use the pin in the c# file like this.

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
// ...
Map map = new Map
{
  // ...
};
Pin pin = new Pin
{
  Label = "Santa Cruz",
  Address = "The city with a boardwalk",
  Type = PinType.Place,
  Position = new Position(36.9628066, -122.0194722)
};
map.Pins.Add(pin);
```